# how can i access to div tag's value in <div value={} /> in react?

Tags: html, reactjs

Using React, i was trying to access my `<div>` tag's value.
so, i put value in `<div>`, just like `<div value></div>`
and then, i make a onClick event to  tag,
just like `<div value={5} onClick={(x)=> console.log(x.target)}></div>`

i can see `<div value={5}></div>` in my console.

so, i put x.taget.value
just like,
`<div value={5} onClick={(x)=> console.log(x.target.value)}></div>`

i expect 5 in my console
but, i wansn't
it shows undefined...

i dont know what i was wrong

```
<span>
        {[...Array(total).keys()]
          .slice(`${number}`, `${number + 3}`)
          .map((e) => (
            <div
              key={e + 1}
              value={e + 1}
              onClick={(x) => console.log(x.target.value)}
            >
              {e + 1}
            </div>
          ))}
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

value is not a valid attribute for div. It is for `input`. You can use an attribute like `id` or even custom attributes starting with `data-`.

```
//Using ID
          <div
              key={e + 1}
              id={e + 1}
              onClick={(x) => console.log(x.target.id)}
            >

//Using data attribute
          <div
              key={e + 1}
              data-value={e + 1}
              onClick={(x) => console.log(x.target.getAttribute('data-value'))}
            >
```

Comment: thank you i truly dont know value is for input. so thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is actually fetching the value property which is available to form/input elements.
What you need to use is `x.target.getAttribute("value")` For a div, `value` is simply an attribute, with no special meaning.

Here is a [sample codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-lamarr-t116b?file=/src/App.js:328-358)

Comment: thank you~ finally i got it, and then i will use it getAttribute next time. thank you